# Open txt file with GVim from webpage link

Tags: firefox, application, gvim

I have a local web page with links to `.txt` files; I want Firefox to open the files with GVim, not in the browser window. How do I do this?

In Firefox "Options" → "General" → "Applications" → "plain text document" I have selected "Use GVim (default)". However, the files continue opening in a browser tab.

I did the same for PHP scripts: "Use GVim"; they open in a GVim window. Precisely the behavior I'm wanting with `.txt` files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, cannot be accomplished. I have searched in 100 locations for an answer. Nothing.

My workaround : change the suffix of my .txt files to .txt.php. Now when I click on a link to open a text file, GVim opens the file.